# Changing object's property value with method

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm kind of new to both JavaScript and jQuery but got some programming experience on other languages. This is what I wrote:

```
var pageFunctionality = {
    value: 0,
    onUpdate: function () {
        $("#numberOfTimes").html(pageFunctionality.value);
        console.log(pageFunctionality.value + "!");
    },
    onBtnClick: function () {
        this.value++;
        console.log(this.value);
        pageFunctionality.onUpdate();
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(pageFunctionality.onBtnClick);
});
```

The problem is this: when I log the "value" inside the "onBtnClick", it clearly increases, but then, when I log it inside the onUpdate method, it keep being 0.

This is the output it produces:

```
1
0!
2
0!
3
0!
4
0!
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: use `pageFunctionality.value` consistently ... `this` in onBtnClick is NOT what you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with the value of `this` in your `onBtnClick()` handler because of the way it is being called from the `.click()` handler.  By default, jQuery will set `this` to be the DOM element that you hooked the event handler to.

If you don't need access to that DOM element in the click handler, then you can change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(pageFunctionality.onBtnClick.bind(pageFunctionality));
});
```

Using `.bind()` like this will override the value of `this` to be what you want it to be.

---

Or, since `pageFunctionality` is a singleton, you could just stop using `this` inside the event handler and refer directly to `pageFunctionality` like this:

```
var pageFunctionality = {
    value: 0,
    onUpdate: function () {
        $("#numberOfTimes").html(pageFunctionality.value);
        console.log(pageFunctionality.value + "!");
    },
    onBtnClick: function () {
        pageFunctionality.value++;
        console.log(pageFunctionality.value);
        pageFunctionality.onUpdate();
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(pageFunctionality.onBtnClick);
});
```